# More elegant way to subscribe with rjxs instead of setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have an `update()` method, with which I search for certain entries in a table and update/filter the entries for each keystroke inside an input field.

My goal is to wait about 400ms after each keystroke before firing the request into the backend so that I avoid too many meaningless requests.

Currently I have implemented it with the `setTimeout()` function, but I am sure that there is a more elegant way with RxJS.

```
  update(searchInput: string) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myService.search(searchInput)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.myArray.content = res;
      });
    }, 400);
  }
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: you need to use debounce instead

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#type-ahead-suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html).
It waits for x miliseconds before emitting anything.
Combining it with other operators to not overload your API would be a good choice.

Your observable would look like

```
const search$ = fromEvent(search, 'input').pipe(
  debounceTime(400), // Wait 400 MS before outputting
  distinctUntilChanged(), // Only output unique values
  map(event => event.target.value), // Extract the value of the search
  switchMap((search) => service.doApi(search)) // SwitchMap to cancel a previous search if it wouldn't have completed
)
search$.subscribe()  // These might leak. Keep them in an array and clean them up when the component unloads
```

Where the search element would be a viewChild of your component.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('yourInput', {static: true}) search: ElementRef;

  searchSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const search$ = fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
      debounceTime(400), // Wait 400 MS before outputting
      distinctUntilChanged(), // Only output unique values
      map((event: KeyboardEvent) => (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value), // Extract the value of the search
      switchMap((search) => service.doApi(search)) // SwitchMap to cancel a previous search if it wouldn't have completed
    )  // Lives forever
    this.searchSubscription = search$.subscribe()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.searchSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that approach. But this way I get the error: "Property 'target' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)" produced by map((event) => event.target.value).

Comment: `fromEvent` data type is currently Type {}. I've updated my answer to use narrow the type of the event to keyboardEvent as the InputEvent type is actually missing from dom.typings

Comment: Now it says: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: Ahh, rookie mistake. nativeElement is only available in the ngOnInit. Let me update my answer

Comment: I also thought it had something to do with life cycle. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I've leave some comments in the code:

```
const search = fromEvent(searchInput, 'input').pipe(
  debounceTime(1000), // Time in milliseconds between key events
  distinctUntilChanged(), // If previous query is different from current   
  map(event => event.target.value) // get value,
  filter(query => query) // if character length greater then 0,
  tap(query => console.log(`About to make an API call with query: ${query}`)),
  switchMap(getCars) // Your api call
);

search.subscribe(successCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" #myId="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="data" />
```

In your component:

```
import {
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged
} from "rxjs/operators";

@ViewChild('myId', {static: true}) myControl: NgModel;

ngOnInit() {
 this.myControl
  .valueChanges // For each changes
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(400),
    distinctUntilChanged()
   )
  .subscribe(() => ...)
```

}

Comment: This would be perfect if you used the pipe syntax and added `switchMap` for the search request. As in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bptdvd

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `debounce()` and `distinctUntileChanged()`:

```
handleFilterEvent = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit(){
    this.handleFilterEvent
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(value => {
            this.myService.search(searchInput)
                .subscribe((res) => {
                    this.myArray.content = res;
            });
        });
}

onSearchChange(value){
    if(value) {
        this.handleFilterEvent.next(value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
   (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `fromEvent` and `Viewchild`

Just reference the ViewChild as follow:

```
@ViewChild('yourInput') inputName: any;
```

Then you can simply use:

```
fromEvent(this.inputName.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .pipe(
                map((k: any) => k.target.value),
                debounceTime(1000)
            )
            .subscribe(value => {
              foo();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is true RXJS way, I have changed `myArray.content` to be `Observable`, as this way you can use piping and mapping. This will prevent multiple requests, more specifically, it will unsubscribe from the previous search before starting new one.

```ts
searchedInput$ = new Subject<string>();
myArray: { content: Observable<any> } = {};

constructor(myService: any) {
  this.myArray.content = this.searchedInput$.pipe(
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    debounceTime(400),
    switchMap(input => myService.search(input)),
  );
}

update(searchInput: string): void {
  this.searchedInput$.next(searchInput);
}
```